# Popup windows sizes

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to create a popup that will have a defined size like the [BBC did](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/). As you can see, when you click "Listen Live", they open a popup player, but I didn't understand how they did that.

Any chance for explanation?

*Sorry, newbie in JavaScript*

Comment: Do you know about the BBC Glow JavaScript library? It's probably in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this function:

```
    openChildWindowWithDimensions = function(url, width, height, showMenu, canResize, showScrollbars) {
        var childWindow = window.open(url, "", "\"width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",menubar=" + (showMenu ? "1" : "0") + ",scrollbars=" + (showScrollbars ? "1" : "0") + ",resizable=" + (canResize ? "1" : "0") + "\"");
        if (childWindow){
            childWindow.resizeTo(width, height);
        }
    }
```

I added the logic to resize the window because of a bug in IE9. Depending on what browser you're using, you may not need that bit.

Comment: Is that what the BBC is doing? Just to make sure... I'm asking about this case specifically.

Comment: I'm not sure what BBC is doing, but this is the most common way of opening a pop-up window. Can you share a link to the page on BBC that you're trying to replicate?

Comment: Sorry, just clicked your link. Yes, this is what they're doing.

Comment: Another thing I noted is that when you resize the popup and then refresh the windows -- it will resize back again. How is that working?

Comment: They are doing something similar to what I'm doing in that function. They're loading the content and then resizing the window to fit it, which can be accomplished using window.resize

Comment: I tried resizing the pop-up and then reloading it, and the window size did not revert back. Did you mean something different?